# Question about the statement ''In four dimensions, there is no antisymmetric tensors of rank higher than four''

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

I am a physicist and I'm studying tensors. In the notes that I got there is this statemente(title) with no proof(I suspect that the proof is difficult). Does anybody know where can I find the proof for it?

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: It's pretty simple actually, suppose $T_{\mu_1 \mu_2 \ldots \mu_5}$ is antisymmetric. Now you can't choose $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_5$ without there being some repeating index (because there are only four different indices). Because of antisymmetry, $T_{\mu_1 \mu_2 \ldots \mu_5}$ then must be identically zero.

Answer (score 1):

If it's antisymmetric in all indices and it has more than four indices, then two of them are going to match (since they can only take one of four values), so it is identically 0.

Answer (score 1):

Another term for antisymmetric tensors is differential forms.

The proof is not difficult. Indeed, the vector space of antisymmetric tensors of rank $k$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space is $\binom nk$. Indeed, if $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, then $\{v_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge v_{i_k}: i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k\}$ gives a basis for $\bigwedge^k V$. (If you like, $v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k$ is an alternative notation for the antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon^{1\dots k}v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_k$.) Note that $\bigwedge^n \Bbb R^n \cong \Bbb R$ (think determinant) and $\bigwedge^k V = 0$ when $k>n=\dim V$.